# Which version of Glut for OpenGL 1.1?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opengl

I am using legacy code that was written for OpenGL 1.1 (from the Windows SDK v7.0A), and uses Glut.

As Glut is not readilty available in the SDK, what version should I download ?

**Update**:

I tried with Glut 3.7, apparently the latest release (copyright up to 1998 ?), just to see, and it seems to work fine. Anyway, I couldn't find compatibility information anywhere...

Comment: What part of "FreeGLUT is backwards compatible with GLUT" do you not understand?

Comment: I am glad with Glut as used in the code, I have no reason to migrate.

Answer (score 5):

You should never use the old GLUT. You should use FreeGLUT, which is backwards compatible with it. And FreeGLUT doesn't have restrictions on which OpenGL version you use (outside of adding support for core profiles and other profile parameters, but those are irrelevant to you).

Comment: @YvesDaoust: You stated that quite clearly in your question. It doesn't change my answer.